# XX-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-wheel

I would like to install XX-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl which is saved in my windows 10 machine.
I tried installing with

```
pip install XX-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I got the error

> ERROR: XX-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

Then I tried installing python 3.6 since I was having only 3.7
I still get the same error

What else can be tried?

Comment: Are you trying to install `XX-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl` on the windows machine?

Comment: What's your python version? Maybe due to the 32bit Python which is incompatible with this 64 bit whl file?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install it on my windows machine

Comment: I am using Python 64 bit version ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: I tried the virtualenv to with to python 3.6, however, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Wheels for Linux are intended to be installed on Linux, not on Windows.